# Simple WebApi Stateless Service on a local ServiceFabric cluster fails to deploy

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to host WebAPI service on local ServiceFabric cluster. However, I'm unable to start even a simple Web Api template provided by VS2017.

I did the following:

1. I prepared the environment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started
2. I created a new project in Visual Studio, choosing "Service Fabric Application", and "Stateless Web API" service template
3. When I build it, and click run, it tries to deploy it but I get the following error:

[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYoUw.png)

And the output is:

> 2>Copying application to image store... 
>  2>Copy application
>   package succeeded 
>  2>Registering application type... 
>   **2>Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType : Operation timed out.** 
>   2>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service
>   Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricS 
>   2>DK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:251 char:9 
>  2>+
>   Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationPathInImage ... 
>   2>+
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
>  2> 
>   + CategoryInfo          : OperationTimeout: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection)
>   [Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType], TimeoutException 
>  2>    +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   RegisterApplicationTypeErrorId,Microsoft.Service  
>  2>
>   Fabric.Powershell.RegisterApplicationType 
>  2>Finished executing
>   script 'Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1'. 
>  2>Time elapsed:
>   00:02:01.7559509 
>  2>**The PowerShell script failed to execute.** 
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== 
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

The interesting part is that when I choose basic "Stateless Service" template in Visual Studio, it works just fine. The problem I have is related to Web Api service on SF. My assumption is that the Web Api project has to write some additional info somewhere on the disk but does not have access to that path.

I tried reinstalling SF and SF SDK but with no results. I'm running VS2017 as an Administrator.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting of your quote block?

Comment: Sure. Now it should look better.

Comment: Did you try to create simple WebApi project and run? Do you have installed IIS?

Comment: It turned out that some of the SF files were encrypted and this caused the issue. Now it's working fine after decryption.